# How to get 2sxc site registered for Patrons?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have 2sxc installed on a site. It was previously registered with the Patrons tokens for Core+, Patron Basic, and Patron Perfectionist.

I patched from 13.10.1 to 14.1.0. Now I get this error on all of my apps:

**Warning: Registration is Invalid. Some features may be disabled because of this. Please reactivate the registration in Apps Management.**

Under System, even though I tried re-registering my app by deleting the old one and starting a new one, I still see "Registered to: (unregistered)"

I went to reactivate my license but it doesn't make a difference. When I go to Extensions/Features, it shows as "Core (free for everyone)" 4/4 but nothing else.

I tried clicking "Retrieve license" but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

How can I register my app to get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the still clumsy process. We'll try to optimize ASAP.

The warning appeared because a major upgrade changes the fingerprint, so the previous activation is invalid. You will need to register the new fingerprint for things to work again.

On features-tab, just click on register and go through the normal steps to activate that fingerprint.

Comment: Ah, got it working. Turns out, I must go to the Extensions/Features tab. I was previously trying to use the "register" link on the "System" tab and that didn't work. Thanks.